# Argument of type 'AnimatedValue<0>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Value | ValueXY'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I was going through React Native documentation for Animation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated

And wrote this simple code

```
import {Animated as RNAnimated} from 'react-native'
 
const ToastGeneric = () => {
  const windowHeight =  useWindowDimensions().height
  const modalPositionY = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const ToastStyleContainer: Record<ToastPosition, ViewStyle> = {
  bottom: {
    bottom: 0,
    marginBottom: bottomSafeArea,
  },
  top: {
    top: 0,
    marginTop: topSafeArea,
  }
 };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (toast.visible) {
      RNAnimated.timing(modalPositionY, {
        toValue: topSafeArea,
        duration: 2000
      }).start();

      setTimeout(() => {
        RNAnimated.timing(modalPositionY, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 2000
        }).start();
      }, 500)
    }

  }, [toast.visible])
```

but I keep getting this error here

```
  RNAnimated.timing(modalPositionY, {
    toValue: topSafeArea,
    duration: 2000
  }).start();
```

> Argument of type 'AnimatedValue<0>' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'Value | ValueXY'.   Type 'AnimatedValue<0>' is missing the
> following properties from type 'Value': setOffset, flattenOffset,
> extractOffset, addListener, and 4 more.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? when I launch the app, it crashed with this error

> TypeError: singleValue.stopTracking is not a function. (In
> 'singleValue.stopTracking()', 'singleValue.stopTracking' is undefined)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo issue. `React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;` should be `React.useRef(new RNAnimated.Value(0)).current;` - `RNAnimated` instead of `Animated`.

You are already imported and renamed `Animated` to `RNAnimated` when you try to import `Animated` from `react-native`.